# Downloading file from model and view in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, download

i'm trying to create a page where users can download some .log file. this is the code :

```
if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("download")){
       String file = (String)request.getParameter("file");
       response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
       "attachment;filename="+file+"");
       response.setContentType("text/plain");

       File down_file = new File("log/"+file);

       FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(down_file);
       ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

       byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
       //copy binary contect to output stream
       while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
       {
        out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
       }
       fileIn.close();
       out.flush();
       out.close();

       return null;
}
```

where am i doing wrong ?
when i click on the download button it correctly ask me to save the file, but it is always a 0 byte file...

Comment: Does `down_file.canRead()` return true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
public void getFile(final HttpServletResponse response) {
  String file = (String) request.getParameter("file");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                     "attachment;filename=" + file);
  response.setContentType("text/plain");

  File down_file = new File("log/" + file);
  FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(down_file);
  ByteStreams.copy(fileIn, response.getOutputStream());
  response.flushBuffer();

  return null;
}
```

where [`ByteStreams.copy`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) comes from wonderful [Google's Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

**EDIT**:

Also, if you are using Spring MVC 3.1 you can do it in cleaner way (that's how I do it, turns out to be one-liner ;)):

```
@Controller
public final class TestController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/some/url/for/downloading/files/{file}",
                    produces = "text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getFile(@PathVariable final String file) throws IOException {
        return Files.toByteArray(new File("log/" + file));
    }

}
```

and in your `servlet.xml` add converter to `mvc:message-converters`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

so that you can return `byte[]` from any `@Controller` method annotated with `@ResponseBody`. Read more [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces) and [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration/).

[`Files.toByteArray`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toByteArray%28java.io.File%29) is also from Guava.

Comment: i have another problem, i tried your code, but i'm still getting a NoClassDefFoundError relative to guava despite i have added the jar in the class path.
P.S. the error come out only at running time, the java file doesn't notice any problem.

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: i solved class path problem, but anyway i'mm still getting 0 byte files when try to download

Comment: i've found where the problem is, 

File down_file = new File("log/" + file);

with absolute path it works, with relative path it doesn't work, WHY ?

Comment: What path does `new File(".").getCanonicalPath()` return?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\bin

i solved using getServletContext().getRealPath("log")+file

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
IOUtils.copy(fileIn, response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();
```

you can find Apache Commons IO here: http://commons.apache.org/io/

[Here](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) you find `IOUtils.copy()` reference.

Comment: Thanx, this helped me as well. Although I've used Spring's [FileCopyUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FileCopyUtils.html) to achieve the same